# Is there a hub gear that can be disengaged?

Tags: internally-geared-hub

When maneuvering a folded bicycle the pedal cranks turn when drive wheel rotates backwards causes difficulty. Do any hub gears have a gear disengage facility to overcome this problem?

Comment: @Criggie - Sounds like a normal bike to me.  If the crank turned when the wheel was rotated forwards then that would suggest that the hub was fouled.

Comment: I've never seen one that had this as a feature. The Sturmey-Archer ASC Fixed-Gear Three-Speed Hub has this as a bug, but I don't think it's manufactured any more. You would need to use a friction shifter instead of the proper one if you wanted to deliberately choose the "neutral" gear, and I'm not sure how well it would stay in that gear.

Comment: What model of folded bicycle is this? Normally this should rarely happen, as you typically carry a folded bicycle, since in folded state it's too small to push on the ground. Some models also have small extra wheels on the luggage rack for pushing when folded, such as the Brompton.

Comment: I take it that you don'the know the answer. Bike is a Dynamic Bicycle Sidekick 8 with Shimano hub gear.

Answer (score 4):

Old, plain, one-gear Velosteel-like hubs had this feature thanks to using rollers instead of cogs, but I suppose it does not meet your expectations.

If you REALLY need this feature you can modify Shimano Nexus 3 to obtain what you want by removing four cogs from part no 4 shown[here](https://www.google.pl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjOmdakr9DMAhWBXCwKHWDLCe8QFggeMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsi.shimano.com%2Fphp%2Fdownload.php%3Ffile%3Dpdf%2Fev%2FEV-SG-3C41-2330B.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEcdHnA7kgVYof90XBa1wFXCJqJ_A&sig2=We85zolVhIyx07w1WFCXcg&bvm=bv.121421273,d.bGg&cad=rja). You will lose 1st gear, rest will work as before.

Comment: That's a cunning solution. Nasty, but cunning. I would never have thought of it.

Comment: MÒŽ it's horribly ugly, I would never do such thing but if author needs what he described more than 1st gear, then it's a matter of choice.